# AdminLite 2.4.0 data table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

Here is the [template](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/tables/data.html), I have copied the contents for the bower_components and dist folders. I also did all the linking and requiring I need or well that I can find to. All requires work no 404's only a status code 200. My code is as follows:

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">Data Table With Full Features</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-header -->
  <div class="box-body">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Rendering engine</th>
          <th>Browser</th>
          <th>Platform(s)</th>
          <th>Engine version</th>
          <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 4.0
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td> 4</td>
          <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 5.0
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 5.5
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td>5.5</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Other browsers</td>
          <td>All others</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>U</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Rendering engine</th>
          <th>Browser</th>
          <th>Platform(s)</th>
          <th>Engine version</th>
          <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
```

I get the table to show fine but non of the search, show X entries, pagination or anything else like that. It seems like I am copying the Hover Data Table but the code shows it is the Data Table With Full Features. I have also included the small script on the page near the bottom at line 1631-1643 it is this:

```
$(function () {
  $('#example1').DataTable();
  $('#example2').DataTable({
   'paging'      : true,
   'lengthChange': false,
   'searching'   : false,
   'ordering'    : true,
   'info'        : true,
   'autoWidth'   : false
  });
});
```

I have tried moving the files aroun

Excuse the poor code styling, it should still give a proper idea.

Comment: do you have any error in your console?

Comment: No errors are coming up, the only thing I get back is that I did a `GET` request and I got a status `200` back. Well server side anyways. Client I get jquery error but it works in other parts of the same page so IDK what that means

Comment: @Monkey_Dev1400 I just moved jQuery up the file and now my page is taking over 7 seconds to load each time but the request times to my server are as expected (I track response times)

Comment: is bootstrap and jquery.dataTables.min.js loaded on the page?

Comment: @Monkey_Dev1400 Yes, I am using Node.js and a template engine, swig. I have a header.html and a footer.html that call CSS and JS files. Then I require those files into the top and bottom of my actual page. This is for making it easier to change the code base up.

Comment: @Monkey_Dev1400 I have gotten all files to load correctly with no errors in chrome's console expect my 1 custom main.js file that has that special bit of JS so I included it in the html file directly as a temp solution. Still not showing up anything even when I go into inspect and look at the elements.

Answer (score 0):

in your script you have set false to "searching"

try to use "true"

```
$(function () {
  $('#example1').DataTable();
  $('#example2').DataTable({
   'paging'      : true,
   'lengthChange': false,
   'searching'   : true, // change this one
   'ordering'    : true,
   'info'        : true,
   'autoWidth'   : false
  });
});
```